# Upload pdf in HTML and Deserialize json file

Tags: html, angularjs, json, spring-data

I'm trying to upload a file in html and then send it to my database via restangular.
My frontend is a combination of angular with typescript but the upload is a form.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <fieldset class="form-group" ng-repeat="field in $ctrl.metadata.fields">
        <label ng-if="field.inputType !== 'hidden'" for="{{field.propertyKey}}"><strong>{{field.name}}</strong></label>
        <input ng-if="field.inputType !== 'select' && field.inputType !== 'file'" class="form-control" type="{{field.inputType}}" name="{{field.propertyKey}}" id="{{field.propertyKey}}" ng-model="$ctrl.data[field.propertyKey]"/>
        <input ng-if="field.inputType === 'file'" class="form-control" ngf-select type="{{field.inputType}}" name="{{field.propertyKey}}" id="{{field.propertyKey}}" ng-model="$ctrl.data[field.propertyKey]"/>
        <sp-dropdown ng-if="field.inputType === 'select'" value="$ctrl.data[field.propertyKey]" api-domain="field.linkedObjectApiDomain" linked-object-name="field.linkedObjectName"></sp-dropdown>
    </fieldset>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="$ctrl.save({item: $ctrl.data})">Save</button>
    <button ng-if="$ctrl.metadata.buttons.hasOpen" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="$ctrl.open()">Open</button>
</form>
```

I did the databinding of the file with [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload).

Upon saving we enter this typescript save method.

```
public save(item: any): any  {
    console.log("item to save is ", item);
    console.log("rapport is ", item["rapport"]);

    if (item.id === undefined) {
        this.restService.save(this.metadata.apiDomain, item).then((addedItem: any) => {
            toastr.success(`${addedItem.naam} successfully created.`, `Overzicht Dossiers Created`);
        });
    } else {
        this.restService.update(this.metadata.apiDomain, item).then((updatedItem: any) => {
            toastr.success(`${updatedItem.naam} successfully updated.`, `Overzicht Dossiers Updated`);
        });
    }
}
```

The second log with the file gives the json:

```
    lastModified:1463402787393
    lastModifiedDate:Mon May 16 2016 14:46:27 GMT+0200 (Romance (zomertijd))
    name:"Rapport.pdf"
    size:83605
    type:"application/pdf"
    upload:Promise
    webkitRelativePath:""
    __proto__:File
```

On server side I'm using a spring project which I didn't set up myself but the important files are my class which should store this data
Dossier

    `/*
     * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
     * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
     * and open the template in the editor.
     */
    package be.ugent.lca.data.entities;`

```
import be.ugent.sherpa.entity.BaseEntity;
import java.sql.Date;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.Lob;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;

/**
 *
 * @author Sam
 */
@Entity
//@JsonDeserialize(using = DossierDeserializer.class) 
//@JsonSerialize(using = DossierSerializer.class) 
public class Dossier extends BaseEntity{
    private String externDossierNr;
    private String internDossierNr;
    private Date datum;
    private Boolean doc;
    private Date refKlantDatum;
    private String refKlantVerwijzing;
    private String verantw;


    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="dossier")
    private Offerte offerte;

    private String status;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "persoon")
    private Persoon persoon;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "OrganisatieFirma")
    private OrganisatieFirma organisatieFirma;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "OrganisatieIntern")
    private OrganisatieIntern organisatieIntern;

    @Lob
    @Column(length=100000)
    private byte[] rapport;

    public Offerte getOfferte() {
        return offerte;
    }

    public void setOfferte(Offerte offerte) {
        this.offerte = offerte;
    }

    public byte[] getRapport() {
        return rapport;
    }

    public void setRapport(byte[] rapport) {
        this.rapport = rapport;
    }

    public OrganisatieFirma getOrganisatieFirma() {
        return organisatieFirma;
    }

    public String getExternDossierNr() {
        return externDossierNr;
    }

    public void setExternDossierNr(String externDossierNr) {
        this.externDossierNr = externDossierNr;
    }

    public String getInternDossierNr() {
        return internDossierNr;
    }

    public void setInternDossierNr(String internDossierNr) {
        this.internDossierNr = internDossierNr;
    }

    public void setOrganisatieFirma(OrganisatieFirma organisatieFirma) {
        this.organisatieFirma = organisatieFirma;
    }

    public OrganisatieIntern getOrganisatieIntern() {
        return organisatieIntern;
    }

    public void setOrganisatieIntern(OrganisatieIntern organisatieIntern) {
        this.organisatieIntern = organisatieIntern;
    }

    public Persoon getPersoon() {
        return persoon;
    }

    public void setPersoon(Persoon persoon) {
        this.persoon = persoon;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public Date getDatum() {
        return datum;
    }

    public void setDatum(Date datum) {
        this.datum = datum;
    }

    public Date getRefKlantDatum() {
        return refKlantDatum;
    }

    public void setRefKlantDatum(Date refKlantDatum) {
        this.refKlantDatum = refKlantDatum;
    }

    public String getRefKlantVerwijzing() {
        return refKlantVerwijzing;
    }

    public void setRefKlantVerwijzing(String refKlantVerwijzing) {
        this.refKlantVerwijzing = refKlantVerwijzing;
    }

    public String getVerantw() {
        return verantw;
    }

    public void setVerantw(String verantw) {
        this.verantw = verantw;
    }

    public Boolean getDoc() {
        return doc;
    }

    public void setDoc(Boolean doc) {
        this.doc = doc;
    }

}
```

and my repository for this class

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package be.ugent.lca.data.repository;

import be.ugent.lca.data.entities.Dossier;
import be.ugent.lca.data.query.DossierQuery;
import be.ugent.sherpa.repository.RestRepository;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource;
/**
 *
 * @author Sam
 */
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "dossiers", path = "dossiers")
public interface DossierRepository extends RestRepository<Dossier, DossierQuery<?>>{

}
```

When trying to save a file to my database the server gives this exception
    Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of byte[] out of START_OBJECT token

This led me to believe that I have to write my own deserializer for Dossier
Thus:

```
package be.ugent.lca.data.entities.deserializers;


import be.ugent.lca.data.entities.Dossier;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.ObjectCodec;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import java.io.IOException;

public class DossierDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer {
    @Override
    public Dossier deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser,
            DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException {
        ObjectCodec oc = jsonParser.getCodec();
        JsonNode root = oc.readTree(jsonParser);
        Dossier dossier = new Dossier();

        dossier.setExternDossierNr(root.get("externDossierNr").asText());
        dossier.setInternDossierNr(root.get("internDossierNr").asText());

        return dossier;
    }
}
```

But my problem is that I don't know how exactly to deserialize the file json, since writing out root.get("rapport") gives back an empty string.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've worked out the file upload.

First of all I split the file upload from the rest of my data so I won't have to rewrite the automatic deserialization for everything that does work.

```
this.restService.save(this.metadata.apiDomain, item).then((addedItem: any) => {
    toastr.success(`${addedItem.naam} successfully created.`, `Overzicht Dossiers Created`);
    console.log("created item ", addedItem);
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("rapport", item["rapport"]);

    this.restService.one('dossiers/' + addedItem.id + '/rapport').withHttpConfig({transformRequest: angular.identity}).customPOST(fd, '', undefined, {'Content-Type': undefined}).then(
        (addedDossier: any) => {
            console.log("posted dossier ", addedDossier);
        }
    );
});
```

In the callback of my normal save I do the custom post to *dossiers/{id}/rapport* for this I need a custom controller.

```
@BasePathAwareController
@RequestMapping("/dossiers/{id}")
@ExposesResourceFor(Dossier.class)
public class DossierController {
```

The BasePathAwawareController makes sure that all automatically generated paths that you don't override keep existing.

```
@Autowired
private DossierRepository dossierRepository;
```

With this I inject my repository to connect to my database.

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/rapport", method = RequestMethod.POST)//,headers = "content-type=multipart/form-data") 
public @ResponseBody String postRapport(@PathVariable("id") Long id,@RequestParam("rapport") MultipartFile file) {
    String name = "rapport";
    System.out.println("Entered custom file upload with id " + id);
    if (!file.isEmpty()) {
        try {
            byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
            Dossier dossier = dossierRepository.findOne(id);
            dossier.setRapport(bytes);

            dossierRepository.save(dossier);
            return "You successfully uploaded " + name + " into " + name + "-uploaded !";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "You failed to upload " + name + " => " + e.getMessage();
        }
    } else {
        return "You failed to upload " + name + " because the file was empty.";
    }
}
```

Like this I'm able to successfully upload my file.

Comment: I'm not sure whether I should include what was wrong with my 'Json string' or if that would needlessly complicate my answer.
Or should I edit that in my question since it wasn't really part of the solution?