# JAVA and Base64 Encoding

Tags: java, web-services, base64

I request a PDF-File over a WebService and write the binary files into a pdf-file. But the PDF-File has errors, so I tried to encode the Base64 by myself:

```
byte[] decBytes = java.util.Base64.getDecoder().decode(rcg.getOrblk());
```

> Illegal base64 character 25

The method:

```
DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(rcg.getOrblk());
```

returns this Base64 code:

> 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

For better understanding:

```
byte[] rawBytes = rcg.getOrblk();
```

When I look into the WebService-Response.xml there are BASE64-Characters but Java automatically returns me byte code.

```
Rcgexpmapfile rcg;


public class Rcgexpmapfile extends Object

Java-Klasse für Rcgexpmapfile complex type. Das folgende Schemafragment gibt den erwarteten Content an, der in dieser Klasse enthalten ist.  <complexType name="Rcgexpmapfile">    <complexContent>
     <restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
       <sequence>
         <element name="Orblk" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}base64Binary"/>
       </sequence>
     </restriction>    </complexContent>  </complexType>
```

Comment: What is your question exactly ?

Comment: Why has my pdf file errors and why the Base64 decoder throws errors?

Comment: Can you open your pdf and read it with e.g. adobe reader?

Comment: I mostly avoided the problem instead of solving it so not sure if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37416299/upload-pdf-in-html-and-deserialize-json-file

Comment: Which kind of errors do you encounter?

Comment: I can open it and get "error by opening stream" (translated from German :/). I miss a picture in the PDF file and when I try to close it, it says "Do you want to save the changes?

Comment: So the PDF file is already broken in the first place and you want to encode it to base64. Yeah this is not going to work.

Comment: For addition Info: The pdf file comes from an SAP-Webservice. When I consume the WebService from an SAP-Consumer-Application and saves the consumed binarys to a pdf file, I have no error and the PDF is perfect. So there is a trouble between JAVA and the data.

Comment: Maybe because SAP is encodeing UTF-16 and JAVA UTF-8?? <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>

Comment: SOLUTION: I encode the data manually in sap and decode it manually in java. And see: it works :)